# Velocity parameter betwetween [ and ] didn't work

Tags: velocity

I write code like following middle of vm file.

```
    #foreach($column in $columnList)
    char        $column.getComponentName()[$column.getComponentLen()];                    
    #end
```

the result

```
char        $column.getComponentName()[$column.getComponentLen()];
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: What is the output you are expecting to achieve?

Comment: for example, the result would be char a[3];

Comment: velocity paramter starting with $ is not changed even if it is not null.

Comment: Have you tried surrounding each variable with `{...}`, i.e. `${column.getComponentName()}`?

Comment: (I've posted that as an answer; please accept it so that this question is not left in the unanswered category.)

Answer (score 0):

Use [formal reference notation](https://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.5/user-guide.html#formalreferencenotation). That is, put `{...}` around the reference:

```
#foreach($column in $columnList)
char        ${column.getComponentName()}[${column.getComponentLen()}];
#end
```

Answer (score 0):

the bracket syntax only works for Velocity 1.7+  prior to that you have to call .get()